# Create specific CPU load

Tags: load, cpu

I am looking for an automated tool, which will enable me to generate a specific load on CPU. e.g Given argument 20, it should create a 20% load on my cpu.

I have already tried lookbusy, stress etc, but they did not work well. I have also written by own bash scripts which do this using fork()-exec() model. But to verify the experiments I am doing, I will require an automated tool.

Thanking in advance for help.

Comment: `automated tool`: this probably belongs on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/). Stackoverflow is usually for Programmatic solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna take a look at this tool : 
http://krash.ligforge.imag.fr/

Answer (score 0):

This script should do what you want: https://github.com/ajurge/CPU_load.git